# How can I create this timetable intelligently? It has changeable periods of time and length

Tags: c#, html, css, user-interface, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a timetable. It will be for a variable number of days, which is causing me a problem.

I have a form which gets several values that decide the layout of my timetable-

- The spaces of time the timetable should be split into (i.e if 30 is
  retrieved, the timetable should be split into chunks of 30mins).
- It will also retrieve a number of (start and end) DateTimes. These reflect the events
  in the timetable. *How can I show these events?*
- The difference between the start time of the event and it's end time
  will always be of exactly the size the chunks of time should be split
  into (i.e in aboves case, 30 mins).

The timetable will always show 12 hours from 7AM to 7PM.

The functionality I would like : A timetable to be displayed, and if the user wishes to choose a certain time from the list of events, then they can click on it and it is inserted into a database.

So far I have as follows :

```
            int duration = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["duration"]); //indicating size of chunks on timetable
            string startDate = Request.Form["startDateYear"] + Request.Form["startDateMonth"] + Request.Form["startDateDay"];
            string endDate = Request.Form["endDateYear"] + Request.Form["endDateMonth"] + Request.Form["endDateDay"]; //both these dates indicate the first day and last day of the timetable to show.
var result = db.Query(//query); //this returns two colums, ds and de which indicate the start time and end time of every event.
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is have a simple timetable displayed with all the times, and events, allowing the user to click whichever they like. What is the best way for me to do this? Would it be possible using the fullcalendar interface?

If anyone has any suggestions for an alternative way of arranging this data, I would be glad to hear of it! :)

Comment: There may be tools out there, but first have you tried it using a paper mock up? You can learn a lot about how you will arrange the events just by moving rectangles of varying sizes about and you can beging to make your own rules that are specific to your problem.

Comment: @ShaunWilde I've done some working out, thanks for the advice. Ultimately, http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx shows exactly the functionality I would like. Getting it to work as I would like is another story though :)